# Trouble in installing RADEON HD 7470M 1GB on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, vga, amd-radeon

I have installed Win 7 32-bit on ASUS X54H laptop which its VGA is RADEON HD 7470M 1GB. I downloaded it's driver from two websites (as follows) but for the two I got a strange message which is "This computer does not meet the minimum requirement for installing the software"!!
I don't know what's the problem because I downloaded it by its correct specs on ASUS website.
Does anyone know why please?

The sites were:
ASUSTeK Computer Inc. -Support- Drivers and Download X54H
Asus X54H drivers for Windows 7 32-bit | laptop drivers, driver updates

Comment: You sure you downloaded the 32-bit version of the drivers?

Comment: Yeah, I chose the Windows 7 32-bit option from the rectangle.

Comment: You should try using http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows 7 - 32 ( all one link )

Comment: try this driver: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd_catalyst_14.1_mobility_betav1.6.exe